# Is "in the briefest of moments" a good synonym for "in the twinkling of an eye"?

Tags: expressions, synonyms, word-usage

I am trying to find a poetic but recognisable synonym of ***in the twinkling of an eye***. [PowerThesaurus](https://www.powerthesaurus.org/in_the_twinkling_of_an_eye/synonyms) gives quite a range of synonyms, but most of them are too colloquial and very few contain *moment, instant*, which is a notion I would need in my phrasing.

Offhand, I thought of [*in the briefest of moments*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22in%20the%20briefest%20of%20moments%22&sxsrf=ALiCzsYfBm1VyMScDmMfg3EuBJnwOfocpQ%3A1661951076281&ei=ZFwPY7rjENvhgAb6rJuYAw&ved=0ahUKEwi6paSckvH5AhXbMMAKHXrWBjMQ4dUDCA4&uact=5&oq=%22in%20the%20briefest%20of%20moments%22&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyBggAEB4QFjIFCAAQhgMyBQgAEIYDOggIABCiBBCwAzoKCAAQHhCiBBCwAzoECCMQJ0oECEEYAUoECEYYAFClClihGGC-IGgBcAB4AIABZIgB6AGSAQMyLjGYAQCgAQHIAQTAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz), but when I looked it up, it seems that it is not terribly common (641K results). *[In the briefest moment](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22in%20the%20briefest%20moment%22&sxsrf=ALiCzsZV_XOTWEckWTx4Hzev9OIvJQOihg%3A1661951083381&ei=a1wPY_TvFsvdgQbotK3IAQ&ved=0ahUKEwi00dWfkvH5AhXLbsAKHWhaCxkQ4dUDCA4&uact=5&oq=%22in%20the%20briefest%20moment%22&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyBggAEB4QDzIFCAAQhgMyBQgAEIYDMgUIABCGAzIFCAAQhgM6BwgAEEcQsAM6BQgAEKIEOgcIABAeEKIESgQIQRgASgQIRhgAUPAHWLwdYIEgaAJwAXgAgAFNiAHKAZIBATOYAQCgAQHIAQjAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz)* gives even less results, and my search of *[in the briefest instant](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22in%20the%20briefest%20instant%22&biw=1536&bih=743&sxsrf=ALiCzsaFf-OZUUlh9sae_khrq95eCOjwWQ%3A1661950548857&ei=VFoPY6D7M5WShbIP5oa2mA0&ved=0ahUKEwig9eSgkPH5AhUVSUEAHWaDDdM4ChDh1QMIDg&uact=5&oq=%22in%20the%20briefest%20instant%22&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyBQgAEKIEMgcIABAeEKIEMgUIABCiBDIFCAAQogQyBQgAEKIEOgkIABAeEA8QsAM6CAgAEIYDELADSgQIQRgBSgQIRhgAUNwQWMYbYPcgaAJwAHgAgAFgiAGdBJIBATeYAQCgAQHIAQTAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz)*, convinced me it is not what I am looking for.

I just wonder if I should still go on and use *in the briefest of moments*. Is it uncommon because it is poetic, or because it sounds awkward to the native ear?

The sentence where I would use the expression is:

> His whole life changed *in the briefest of moments/moment*.

Note that I would need the sentence to have a literary, slightly dated feel.

Comment: As popularity does not define goodness, you now have permission to use it. It's good.

Comment: "in the briefest of moments" is not a set phrase. Also it is not awkward at all, it very transparently means "a moment that is very brief" with a tiny bit of hyperbole. As to writing advice, don't pin all your stylistic desires on a single expression - "a literary, slightly dated " doesn't have to happen in this very sentence. But yes, 'in the twinkling of an eye' is cliche and dated and too informal, like a leprechaun clicking his heels and disappearing.

Comment: I have already used once the "twinkling" in this chapter anyway, so here I definitely need to find a replacement. And yes, _because_ "in the briefest of moments" is not a set phrase, I was wondering if it is ok to use it in this context.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing *wrong* with "in the briefest of moments" - it's grammatical, and the meaning will certainly be understood. But I wouldn't say that it's particularly *poetic*; it's quite literal and lacks the imagery that *twinkling of an eye* suggests; also it's a little verbose (for a phrase suggesting a short period of time).

There are certainly alternatives. I'm not sure what may be to your liking, here are some suggestions that are more metaphorical and/or shorter:

- In a snap
- In a flash
- In two shakes (of a lamb's tail)
- In a trice
- In the blink of an eye
- In a split second
- In a heartbeat

Comment: Yes, all these alternatives were already mentioned in the PowerThesaurus link I provided, but they do not have the literary, slightly dated feel I am looking for. As for the length of the phrase, _in the briefest of moments_ has even less words that _in the twinkling of an eye_. Plus, I would need the word "moment" or "instant" in the expression. But thanks for confirming that the expression is not awkward.

Comment: @fev: If what you want is "literary, slightly dated" then you should put that in the question - what you've asked for is "poetic", which (in my view) your preferred phrase isn't really, but it _does_ have a "literary, slightly dated", so go for it :)

Comment: Point taken, will edit.

Comment: *trice* definitely has a slightly dated feel.